# how to insert text in header using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below code,

```
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style= "width:30%;">
          <img class = "new" src="images/new-icon.png">
        <td>
            <h1>Hello there!</h1>
          <p>Thanks for logging in
            <span class = "blue">image edit application</span>.
            Get started by reading our
            <a href = "https:abc">documentation</a>
            or use the xxxxxxxxxxxx.
    </table>
  </body>
```

In the above code, i want to add extra text after "Hello there!" in the header

using selenium webdriver with java script. Please help.

I tried clicking on Hello there by locating it with xpath and trying to add text using sendKeys. I dont see any text added and code does not throw any error.
I am trying to edit a html file on a online editor using selenium

Comment: please share code which you have written to sent text using selenium. Also you can insert text only in textbox, richtext box. you are trying to insert in h1 tag? seems not possible.

Comment: Are you sure the text there is editable? It doesn't look like it is from the HTML you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing JS in the browser using `executeScript()` function. You'll have to write a JavaScript code which will append/replace the text.

I'm not familiar with Selenium with JS but this a rough code which you can try out.

```
script = "theParent = document.getElementByTagName('body');
theKid = document.createElement('div');
theKid.innerHTML = 'Hello There!';

// append theKid to the end of theParent
theParent.appendChild(theKid);

// prepend theKid to the beginning of theParent
theParent.insertBefore(theKid, theParent.firstChild);"

driver.executeScript('return ' + script).then(function(return_value) { 
    console.log('returned ', return_value);
});
```

Comment: I tried adding the code and running the script : i get below error : 
script = "theParent = document.getElementByTagName('body');
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[launcher] Error : SyntaxError : Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @user5462020 - I'm sorry, not familiar with Selenium with JS but the code will look somewhat similar to what I've done.